# What documentation is needed to show German nationality before 1913?

Tags: citizenship, dual-citizenship, german-citizens

For the purposes of claiming German citizenship through descent, what documents are needed to show that an individual held German citizenship before passage of the nationality law of 1913?

Is a birth certificate adequate? Marriage certificate?

Answer (score 2):

The present day Citizenship Laws are based on the version of:

- Gesetz vom 15. Mai 1935 (RGBl. I. S. 593)

Before that the German Nationality was based on the Citizenship of a **Bundesstaat** that was a member of the German Empire

- similar in nature to **European Union** Citizenship today

**Reichs- und Staatsangehörigkeitsgesetz vom 22. Juli 1913**

> § 1. Deutscher ist, wer die Staatsangehörigkeit in einem Bundesstaat (§§3 bis 32) oder die unmittelbare Reichsangehörigkeit (§§ 33 bis 35) besitzt.
>
> § 3. Die Staatsangehörigkeit in einem Bundesstaate wird erworben:
>   1. durch Geburt (§ 4),
>   2. durch Legitimation (§ 5),
>   3. durch Eheschließung (§ 6),
>   4. für einen Deutschen durch Aufnahme (§§ 7, 14, 16) und
>   5. für einen Ausländer durch Einbürgerung (§§ 8 bis 16).

Before 1913, the laws of each Bundesstaat determined the Citizenship

- Prussia of 31st December 1832

  - had the conditions 1-3, 5 of the law of 22. Juli 1913

for the others I assume the same.

So the process has not changed.

Then, as now, you apply for a **Staatsangehörigkeitsausweis**

- checking for Birth and Marriage Certificates will be done at the appropriate **Standesämter**

as part of the process.